# Use GetOpenFileName and then VLookup on that workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make the macro to open another workbook with GetOpenFileName and then use Vlookup to look up some values on that workbook.

With my code, it can find the name of the workbook, but not the name of the sheet. Here is my actual code:

```
Sub LookUpGetOpen()

Dim UserFile As String, MyPath As String, MyFile As String

UserFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Open file from your desktop")

MyPath = Left(UserFile, InStrRev(UserFile, "\"))
MyFile = Mid(UserFile, InStrRev(UserFile, "\") + 1)

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'" & MyPath & "[" & MyFile & "]& Worksheets(1).Name &R1C1:R100C2,2,0)"

End Sub
```

The part of the *& Worksheets(1).Name &* is where I fail, as if I introduce the name of the sheet, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you won't know in advance the name of the worksheet, the workbook will need to be opened.  Once the formula is entered into the desired cell, the opened workbook can be closed.

Here are some other suggestions...

1) You should specify a file filter for `GetOpenFilename`, so that only Excel workbooks can be selected.

```
UserFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx;*.xlsm), *.xlsx;*.xlsm", , "Open file from your desktop")
```

2) You should check whether the user has cancelled when prompted to select a file. Note that `UserFile` is declared as Variant, since `GetOpenFilename` returns a String when successful, and False when the user cancels.

```
Dim UserFile As Variant
UserFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx;*.xlsm), *.xlsx;*.xlsm", , "Open file from your desktop")

If UserFile = False Then Exit Sub 'user cancelled
```

Here's your macro, which has been amended accordingly...

```
Sub LookUpGetOpen()

    Dim UserFile As Variant
    UserFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx;*.xlsm), *.xlsx;*.xlsm", , "Open file from your desktop")

    If UserFile = False Then Exit Sub 'user cancelled

    Dim activecellRange As Range
    Set activecellRange = ActiveCell

    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=UserFile, ReadOnly:=True)

    With sourceWorkbook
        activecellRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[" & .Name & "]" & .Worksheets(1).Name & "'!R1C1:R100C2,2,0)"
    End With

    sourceWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set sourceWorkbook = Nothing
    Set activecellRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I introduce your code, it seems that "Worksheets(1).Name" refers to the first sheet in the actual workbook, not the first sheet in the workbook I am looking up. Any idea?